# How to select inner type that is part of a union

Tags: typescript

Selecting inner types (`Type['fieldName']`) in Typescript is very useful, with it you don't need to think of so many unique names for things. But I don't know how to select those inner types **without giving them unique names** when they are part of an union

Is it possible to figure out the values of those `?` in the snippet below in order to get the type in the comment?

```js
type A = {
  b:
    | {
        c: boolean;
      }
    | {
        d: number;
      }
    | null
    | undefined;
};

type Conly = A["b"][?] // { c: boolean }
type Donly = A["b"][?] // { d: number }
type CorD = A["b"][?]; // { c: boolean } | { d: number }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to find where `A["b"]` intersects with the target type.

```
type Conly = Extract<A["b"], { c: any }>
type Donly = Extract<A["b"], { d: any }>
```

`CorD` is a union of these two.

```
type CorD = Conly | Donly;
```

Note that you can also get `Cord` by removing `null | undefined` from `A["b"]`.

```
type CorD = NonNullable<A["b"]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [conditional helper types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), namely [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) and [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet):

```
type Conly = Extract<A["b"], Record<"c", any>> // { c: boolean }
type Donly = Extract<A["b"], Record<"d", any>> // { d: number }
type CorD = NonNullable<A["b"]>; // { c: boolean } | { d: number }
```

[Live code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=67&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTUBGAudWUAPsgYVgMa44D2NANhAIYB2A3GZgL6fGkblMAE2osArgFtsEAE4cB3XiXH16SqGJZCIAMwCWLCEPld56UJCgBhGi3ogEUAKIAPYDKYVgAHhgBtACJsAIBdABooACUIChoZIW8AigCI1hAAPnSoAHps5CgqWgZmFigeNAtoABFbe0dXd08ffyDQiOjY%20MShFKg0zJy8pCgRKHEpWTLzcGgbGSrHADlbRbFVJmxGX0DgkPS2QfzC7DpGVjK%20YdHx6RkyoA)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not support `Union` to `Tuple` conversion. Instead, you can use `Tuple` then convert to `Union`.

```
type A = {
  b:[{ c: boolean } , { d: number}, null , undefined]
};

type B = A['b'][number]

type C = A['b'][0] // { c: boolean }
type D = A['b'][1] // { d: number }
type CorD = NonNullable<B> // { c: boolean } | { d: number }
// Another ways
type CorD_2 = Extract<B, C | D> // { c: boolean } | { d: number }
type CorD_3 = Exclude<B, null | undefined> // { c: boolean } | { d: number }
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I wanted because it modifies the A type. My data is of original type A from my question, but I would like to be able to reference a specific entity in the union of a subfield of A

as a further explanation, I am using code generation to generate TS types from a graphql schema, so I can't modify the TS type at all, yet I would like to be able to reference parts of that type (for example as the type of an argument to a function)

Comment: In that case you can use `type T = Extract<A["b"], { t: any }>`